# Include $or in mongo query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query running on node using mongoose.

```
Contacts.find().where("_id",id).where("types","presenter").exec(function(err,doc){
```

Now I would like to include another value which is `Presenter` to the second where clause.

I tried with the following

```
Contacts.find().where("_id",presenter).where("types","presenter", $or ["types","Presenter"] ).exec(function(err,doc){
```

But the error is `$or is undefined` which is quite obvious.

How can I pass both values `presenter`, `Presenter` within the second where clause.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator.
`...where('types').in(['presenter', 'Presenter'])...`